# How can I change the value of parent's prop using click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to use the `componentWillUnmount` functionality of React and to change the value of a prop from a child component by click event. I think I am willing to use the "lift the state up" and want to use the `componentWillUnmount` property of React.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      show:true
    }
  }
  render() {
    const toggleDisplay=()=>{
      this.setState({show:!this.state.show});
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.show&&<ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class ChildrenUnmounting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert("constructor is called!");
    this.state={
      onclickfun:props.onclickfun,
    }
    alert("constructor is called!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {alert("render is called!")}

        <h1>This content is shown!</h1>
        <button onClick={this.state.onclickfun}>
          Toggle View
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert("componentWillUnmount is called!");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added an answer down below. I'm not sure what you mean by wanting to use `componentWillUnmount` property of React. It's unnecessary here if your goal is to just update the `show` state variable.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly passing down the state setter down to the child component. Instead, you're setting it to a state value/variable.

Here how the code should be:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: true
    }
  }

  const toggleDisplay = () => {
    this.setState({ show:!this.state.show });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.show && <ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildrenUnmounting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert("constructor is called!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {alert("render is called!")}

        <h1>This content is shown!</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.onclickfun}>
          Toggle View
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert("componentWillUnmount is called!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Appcomponent's render() method, you are using this.show instead of this.state.show. Update the line

```
{this.show&&<ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}
```

to

```
{this.state.show && <ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}.
```

With this change, the show state property will be properly referenced in the render() method and the child component will be shown or hidden based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

In your `App` component's return function, the condition has an incorrect variable (`this.show` in place of `this.state.show`). Because of that, you are facing such issue.

Current Code:

```
{this.show && <ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}
/*^^^^^^^*/
```

Update Like This:

```
{this.state.show && <ChildrenUnmounting onclickfun={toggleDisplay} />}
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
```